# Name error for ensure inclusion of?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec-rails

In my model I have the follow to test with:

```
UNIT_TYPES = [ 'seconds', 'minutes', 'hours', ]
validates_inclusion_of :unit_type, :in => UNIT_TYPES, :allow_blank => true
```

and using [shoulda-matchers](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/blob/master/lib/shoulda/matchers/active_model/ensure_inclusion_of_matcher.rb) I put:

```
it { should ensure_inclusion_of(:unit_type).in_array(UNIT_TYPES) }
```

But why do I get this error?

Failures:

```
  1) Price inclusions
     Failure/Error: it { should ensure_inclusion_of(:unit_type).in_array(UNIT_TYPES) }
     NameError:
       uninitialized constant UNIT_TYPES
     # ./spec/models/price_spec.rb:39:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you want to call your Model constant out side the Model use `<ModelName>::<ConstantVariableName>`

Change

```
UNIT_TYPES
```

To

```
User::UNIT_TYPES #Assuming 'User' is your Model Name
```

So your `shoulda` code should be something like following

```
it { should ensure_inclusion_of(:unit_type).in_array(User::UNIT_TYPES) }
```